# The average derivative of an infinite curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus

Is this even a well-formed question, and if so, does it have an approach?

For example, I'd like to say that, by symmetry, a parabola's average derivative would be zero. But that doesn't sit well with me... I mean, how would I even compute such an average??

$$\overline{f'(x)} = \dfrac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)\ dx}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ dx}$$

That's nonsense, right?

Comment: Yes, that formula is nonsense. A reasonable definition of the average of $g$ over $\Bbb R$ is $\lim_{A\to\infty}\frac1{2A}\int_{-A}^Ag(x)\,dx$, _if_ the limit exists. Another is $\lim_{A,B\to\infty}\frac1{A+B}\int_{-A}^Bg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written the formula is not literally true.  One can write
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{ \displaystyle\int_{-a}^a f'(x)\,dx }{\displaystyle\int_{-a}^a 1\,dx}
$$
and that would indeed be equal to $0$, but if you let the upper and lower bounds of integration grow at different rates you'll get something other than $0$.  This is akin to a Cauchy principal value, but with Cauchy principal values you would take limits of each integral separately.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up Cauchy p.v.. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

A way to have a good definition of average derivative is to first start by defining a probability distribution for a random point along the curve and then you can determine a distribution for the derivative at that point and then you can find the expected value of that. Your current question is equivalent to asking the following:

> suppose I pick a random real number and then double it. What would be the average value?

If the curve is within a bounded region then you might be able to come up with a distribution that feels uniform.